# Issues with Foreach Loops with JSP, JSTL and EL

Tags: java, jsp, web, jstl

I'm trying to do a standard foreach loop with JSTL, but can't seem to get it to work. The data exists, as the other parts of the jps page work. However this foreach loop does not:

```
        <p> Script version
        <% // scrip version
            List test = (List)request.getAttribute("names");

            out.println(test.get(0).toString());
        %>
        </br>
        El version
        </br>
        ${names}
        </br>
    <c:forEach var="name" items="${names}">
        He is: ${name} </br>
    </c:forEach>
    </p>
```

I'm unsure as to why this is the case? The script version works, and just printing out ${names} gives me a view of the List. But the foreach doesn't work.

names is a list sent through from my controller class.

Any help would be great! Cheers!

Comment: Have you added the JSTL tag lib at the top of your JSP file.

Comment: When you have such a problem, always look at the source code of the generated HTML in the browser. My guess is that you'll find `<c:forEach>` inside, indicating that the tags have not been executed by the server, indicating that you forgot to declare the taglib.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks go to [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) and[JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) for pointing me in the correct direction.
I needed to include the JSLT library at the top of my JSP page. 
To do this, you need to include the library in your project, as well as declare it at the top using this line:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

For other tag libraries, you need to do the same.

Thanks guys for sending me in the right direction!